# Livewire 3: Not able to bind to eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire Component "UpdateCategory" in which I am passing the "category" as prop.
In "UpdateCategory" component `mount` method I am initializing a public property "category" and trying to bind `category.name` to an input field but it is not working.

It throws the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`

My Code:

## category.blade.php

```html
<x-feathericon-edit wire:click.prevent="updateCategory({{ $category->id }})" class="w-5 h-5 text-blue-700 cursor-pointer" />

<livewire:admin.categories.update-category :show="$showUpdateModal" :category="$selectedCategory" />
```

## Category.php

```php
public bool $showUpdateModal = false;

public ?Category $selectedCategory;

public function updateCategory(Category $category)
{
    $this->selectedCategory = $category;
    $this->showUpdateModal = true;
    $this->dispatch('open-modal', 'update-category');
}
```

## UpdateCategory.php

```php
public Category $category;

public function mount(Category $category)
{
    $this->category = $category;
}
```

## update-cateogry.blade.php

```html
<x-text-input
    id="name"
    type="text"
    class="mt-1 block w-3/4"
    placeholder="{{ __('Category Name') }}"
    wire:model.live="category.name"
/>
                        

<p class="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ $category->name}}<p>
<p class="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ $category->slug }}<p>
```

The strange thing is that the name & slug in the paragraph is printed properly but the binding is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. It worked under Livewire 2 but no longer under Livewire 3.
Model binding has been deactivated. However, it is possible to activate this behavior.

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#eloquent-model-binding

> In Livewire 3, binding directly to Eloquent models has been disabled
> in favor of using individual properties, or extracting Form Objects.
>
> However, because this behavior is so heavily relied upon in Livewire
> applications, version 3 maintains support for this behavior via a
> configuration item in config/livewire.php:

Answer (score 0):

This is all **extremely** well documented and explained in the official Livewire 3 documentation.

I think you are becoming confused with which component you are talking to, to be honest.

You are opening a new component, but not passing anything to the mount function, so it's unaware of anything that has happened before.

I strongly suggest, in the kindest possible way, that you review the docs that are published.

Alternatively, there are a large number of available freelancers (I am not one of them) available if you post on the Livewire Discord.
There's also a large community in the Discord Help channel, and you may get some answers there.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do model binding on a function call. Livewire doesn't work that way. It even gives [examples in the docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/actions#passing-parameters) where it's clear you need to do your *own* model resolving when using actions, unless you happen to perform your action on a model *property*, aka one that is being hydrated by Livewire.

So, simply stated:

```php
public function updateCategory(int $categoryId)
{
    $category = Categorory::findOrFail($categoryId);
    // 

}
```